# Was a Mossad impostor hanged instead of Saddam Hussein?

Tags: history

So a colleague has shown me this story: "[Fake Saddam Sentenced to Death](http://www.conspiracyplanet.com/channel.cfm?channelid=104&contentid=4034&page=2)", in which it is claimed that the man who was said to be Saddam Hussein in his court-case was an impostor.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: it's known Saddam had a lot of lookalikes. That's probably where the myth/conspiracy theory originated (though I doubt the Mossad would supply them). But IMO it's just another conspiracy theory, you'd have to discredit the DNA testing that was done to identify Saddam.

Comment: @jwenting: I've heard about the lookalikes claim, but is it well documented?

Comment: I can shed some light on it: it's a conspiracy theory propounded by lunatics.

Comment: @DJClayworth - but it's an **elegant** conspiracy theory. At least it makes some geopolitical sense, lunacy aside.

Comment: @jwenting - was there DNA testing done on the body? If so, just put that as an answer, it oughtta be sufficient.

Comment: @DVK *Every* conspiracy theory that is worth it's money makes "some geopolitical sense". This of course doesn't make it true.

Comment: IMO the burden of proof here is on the conspiracy theorists. The ONLY resources I can find claiming the executed person wasn't Saddam (which would make him a standin volunteering to be executed, after Saddam was already captured...) are conspiracy theorist sites (mostly focussed around the old "Bush is evil" mantra). But lack of evidence for a claim isn't accepted as an answer here, so I can't use that.